# How can I exclude the bin folder from Visual Studio publish?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I want to exclude the bin folder from being copied to the publish directory.

Using Visual Studio 2015, Asp.Net Web Application Project

Below is my .pubxml file. Notice that "bin" is listed inside the ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment element. All of the other folders listed there are excluded as expected, but this bin folder is still copied!

The bin directory is different I imagine as it is not part of the project, but part of the build output. My build output path is pointing to a different directory than my publish and working correctly. why is the bin still being copied to the publish output directory?? can it be excluded??

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
This file is used by the publish/package process of your Web project. You can customize the behavior of this process
by editing this MSBuild file. In order to learn more about this please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208121. 
-->
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>Web.config;Default.aspx;packages.config</ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>
    <ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>bin;js;TestingUtils;TestPages;UI</ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <publishUrl>C:\website</publishUrl>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>True</DeleteExistingFiles>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 1):

I just inserted `<ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>bin</ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>` in my publish profile and it didnt include bin folder

Comment: What version of Visual Studio? I am using VS 2015, and am also using a list of folders like `<ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>bin;folder1;folder2</ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>`. This does not work for me

Comment: I am using VS 2015 too

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following tag in your xml publish profile:

```
<ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>bin<
```

Comment: edited question to make clear I am already doing this, and it is not working